# Move table to the right

Tags: tables

Is it possible to align table to the right?

I tried `\hfill`, but seems not working with the tables:

```
\hfill\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|c|l|c|c|}
\cline{2-5}
Zestawienie VAT: & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wartość\\ netto {[}zł{]}\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Stawka\\ VAT\end{tabular}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wartość\\ VAT {[}zł{]}\end{tabular}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wartość\\ brutto {[}zł{]}\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-5} 
                 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                                                                             & zw                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,00}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                                                                              \\ \cline{2-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: A `table` is a floating container thus it isn't actualy there for `\hfill` to push on. If you want to move the tabular then move the `\hfill` inside your `table` container.

Comment: It is working, thanks :)

Comment: Do you *really* need the `table` environment?

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the `\raggedleft` directive inside the table environment. I took the opportunity to simplify the code of your tabular, in particular replacing the nested tabulars with the simpler `\Centerstack` from `stackengine` and using `\rowcolor` at the beginning of the fist row.

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\raggedleft\begin{tabular}[t]{l|c|l|c|c|}
\cline{2-5}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\cellcolor{white}Zestawienie VAT: & \bfseries\Centerstack{Wartość\\ netto [zł]} & \bfseries\Centerstack{Stawka\\ VAT} & \bfseries\Centerstack{Wartość\\ VAT [zł]} & \bfseries\Centerstack{Wartość\\ brutto [zł]} \\ \cline{2-5}
                 & & zw & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,00} & \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

- IN colored cells are beter seen horizontal lines defined by `hhline` package, so instead of `cline{2-3}` is better to use `\hhline{~|----|}`.
- Below are two examples of your table. However, I wonder why you have cells in the first column without border. Since the context of this is unknown it seems quite strange ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, hhline}
\newcommand\MakeCell[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\bfseries\small}c @{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|*{4}{S[table-format=2.2]|}}
    \hhline{~|----|}
Zestawienie VAT:    & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Wartość\\ netto [zł]}} 
                        & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Stawka\\ VAT}} 
                            & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Wartość\\ VAT [zł]}} 
                                & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Wartość\\ brutto [zł]}} 
                                        \\ 
    \hhline{~|----|}
                    &  & {zw}                                                                                                         
                            & 0.00
                                &       \\
    \hhline{~|----|}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
or
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \raggedleft
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|*{4}{S[table-format=2.2]|}}
    \hhline{~|----|}
Zestawienie VAT:    & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Wartość\\ netto [zł]}}
                        & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Stawka\\ VAT}}
                            & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Wartość\\ VAT [zł]}}
                                & \cellcolor{gray!50}{\MakeCell{Wartość\\ brutto [zł]}}
                                        \\
    \hhline{~|----|}
                    &  & {zw}
                            & 0.00
                                &       \\
    \hhline{~|----|}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}    
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Do not exist a simple shift command? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, i don't know if it exist :-(

Comment: I'm joking :-))

Comment: I suspect this ... and since now I enjoy (very)  short vacation in Dalmatia  i'm not serious ;-)